# VIM - Combine line from multiple files into single file

Tags: vim

I'm trying to walk through my buffers list, select a single line from each buffer, and to have them all concatenated into a single file (or other buffer). As in:

file1

...
line2
...

file2

...
line2
...

file3

...
line2
...

and so on.

all into:

myfile

line2 (file1)

line2 (file2)

line2 (file3)

I can't seem to get my registers working, and bufdo is causing me heartache for some reason...

[clarification]
I was hoping I could use bufdo to walk through all my buffers, yank the second line from each, and append it into a register.

Then on another file, just paste the register contents into it (containing the second line from all of my buffers).

Comment: (1) Your question isn't complete (what are you actually doing, and you mean by "can't get my registers working" and "heartache"?), and (2) why do you have to do this in Vim when you could just use normal *nix utilities to grab the second line from each file?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should clarify.  gVIM 7.3.46 on Win 7, so no access to any normal *nix commands.  Just wanted to quickly be able to combine these directly from VIM (where I was working on other things already). i was hoping i could just load up my buffers, and yank the second line from each buffer into a register (appended), then be able to just paste the register back into my file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this with something like:

```
bufdo normal 2G"Ayy
```

which iterates through the buffers and runs the given command in normal mode. `2G` jumps to the appropriate line, and `"Ay` yanks into register a, appending instead of overwriting (since the A is capitalized). Make sure register a is empty before you start!

You can use `windo` or `tabdo` if you have windows or tabs instead of buffers.

Comment: Aaand, there it is staring me in the face.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I never knew how to append to a register. Thank you!

Comment: @Pat You can use command-mode command `:bufdo 2yank A` instead.

Comment: @ZyX: Quite true! I tend to fall back to `:normal` since a lot of things are hard to get done in command mode.

Comment: @Jefromi I tend to do the opposite and create functions because normal-mode commands have very large number of side-effects (touching registers, jumplist, remappings, various special marks) - when I write something to share. Solutions for internal use are less restricted, but I still never forget about bang after normal and `nore` where possible.